# Access nested value in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a Firebase newbie and I would like to figure out how to access deep nested data in Realtime Database.
Let's suppose I have the following structure:

[image]

I would like to get the block of data in which location -> Id value corresponds to **3154380**, (in this case is the second one)

How could achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the sub-path in `.orderByChild` and use `.equalTo`:

```
database().ref('reports').orderByChild('location/id').equalTo('3174380');
```

However, I will say, you should really look at [flattening your data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/structure-data#flatten_data_structures) for best performance and usability in this environment.